# MemoryCache absoluteExpiration and memory limit

Tags: c#, datetime, azure, asp.net-mvc-5, memorycache

I am coding a MVC 5 internet application, and am using the `MemoryCache` object for caching objects. I see that using the `MemoryCache.Set` method, an `absoluteExpiration` can be specified.

If I use the following way to add and retrieve an object from the `MemoryCache`, what is the `absoluteExpiration` set to:

```
cache['cacheItem'] = testObject;

TestObject testObject = cache['cacheItem'] as TestObject;
```

Also, when using the `MemoryCache` in an MVC internet application, should I set the amount of memory that can be used for the `MemoryCache`, or is the default implementation safe enough for an Azure website?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is equivalent to calling Add, like below:

```
cache.Add("cacheItem", testObject, null);
```

The added entry would have the default expiration time, which is infinite (i.e., it doesn't expire). See the [MSDN on CacheItemPolicy.AbsoluteExpiration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.cacheitempolicy.absoluteexpiration(v=vs.110).aspx) for details.

To answer the question about memory usage: (from [CacheMemoryLimitMegabytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.configuration.memorycacheelement.cachememorylimitmegabytes(v=vs.110).aspx) Property):

> The default is zero, which indicates that MemoryCache instances manage their own memory based on the amount of memory that is installed on the computer.

I would say that it's safe to let the MemoryCache defaults decide how much memory to use, unless you're doing something really fancy.

Comment: Sorry, I did not post the add to cache code. Does my code achieve the same result as the code in your answer?